# PHP is not executing in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have created an index html page and in the head I would like to execute a php script.

At the moment it looks like so:

```
<head>
        <title>The Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <?php
            $file = "uploads/data.xml";
            if (file_exists($file)){
                echo "The file $file exists.";
            }else{
                echo "The file $file does not exist.";
            }
        ?>

    </head>
```

I tried to rename the index file from `index.html` to `index.php` however, this still doesn't work.
Even in the editor the code between the `<?php ?>` tags are greyed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you serving the file through apache?

Comment: The *editor* has nothing to do with the *execution environment* or *execution* of such code - the highlighting is entirely separate (as is the highlighting on SO, for instance). You need to *execute* the PHP appropriately (e.g. with Apache server).

Comment: Not quite sure how to rectify this question and its reputation of -6. It's understandable that the editor didn't determine the issue. The issue was running the file through a server. Why does that mean the question has received so many negative votes and been put on hold after a solution was found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colour of the code in your editor has no bearing on the result. In my editor, both "invalid HTML tag" and "PHP tag" are red(-ish), but that doesn't mean they're the same ;)

Now, as for your problem, you need to be running this on a server. Just loading the file in your browser is not enough.

If you have PHP (5.4 or newer) installed on your own computer, you can start a "development server" real easily: open up a command prompt (terminal, whatever), navigate to the folder your file is in, then run this:

```
/path/to/php -S localhost:8000
```

Then open your browser and go to `http://localhost:8000/`. Boom! PHP file, run!

Comment: Here's an anecdote that may bring amusement: I spent months writing a PHP script that would listen for incoming connections on port `8000`, then start PHP and process the HTTP request - in short, a PHP server written in PHP. Not three days after perfecting it for development, they announced PHP 5.4 with its built-in server!

Comment: Lesson in that is read the announcements!

Comment: @ScottMcGready I made the server *just before* the announcement ;)

Comment: Now, that *is* unlucky ;)

Comment: Speaking of "listening"; maybe PHP were listening in on "you" ;-)

Comment: You're thinking of another three letter agency Fred.

Comment: Hehe, something similar happened with Pokémon: I just designed my new Absol character, and three days later they reveal Mega Absol, with the *same tail design!*